# xslt collapsing neighbouring siblings with identical attribute into one while concatenating their text

Tags: xml, xslt

Background: the following is an xslt modified xml extract of an MSWord form. Some text from the MSWord form somehow gets split into multiple elements and needs to be recombined into a single element. Below is an actual snippet of the penultimate XML input

```
<Section coord="2.13" posn="2" of="13">
    <Segment coord="1.25" rowno="1" of="25">
        <Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table">QUAL</Entry>
        <Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table">I</Entry>
        <Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table">FICATIONS</Entry>
    </Segment>
    <Segment coord="2.25" rowno="2" of="25">
        <Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table">ACADEMIC QUALIFICATIONS</Entry>
        <Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table"> (Most recent first)</Entry>
    </Segment>
    <Segment coord="3.25" rowno="3" of="25">
        <Entry coord="1.4" colno="1" of="4" desgn="Column">Degree/Diploma/Certificate</Entry>
        <Entry coord="2.4" colno="2" of="4" desgn="Column">Institution</Entry>
        <Entry coord="3.4" colno="3" of="4" desgn="Column">Date Conferred</Entry>
        <Entry coord="3.4" colno="3" of="4" desgn="Column">(mm/yyyy)</Entry>
        <Entry coord="4.4" colno="4" of="4" desgn="Column">SAQA Evaluated?</Entry>
        <Entry coord="4.4" colno="4" of="4" desgn="Column">(If not SA qualification)</Entry>
    </Segment>
    <Segment coord="4.25" rowno="4" of="25"/>
    <!-- remaining 21 Segments from Section deleted ... -->
</Section>
```

Note: The @coord attribute is constructed from sibling "position().last()".

The desired merge output:
In the Segment with @coord 1.25 for example, the three Entries need to be collapsed into one Entry:

`<Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table">QUALIFICATIONS</Entry>`

where their texts are concatenated into one.

Likewise Segment 1.26 has two Entries that should collapse into:

```
<Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table">ACADEMIC QUALIFICATIONS (Most recent first)</Entry>
```

The same applies to the last two in Segment 3.25, with distinct merged Entries:

```
<Entry coord="3.4" colno="3" of="4" desgn="Column">Date Conferred(mm/yyyy)</Entry>
```

and

```
<Entry coord="4.4" colno="4" of="4" desgn="Column">SAQA Evaluated?(If not SA qualification)</Entry>
```

I am able (in document order) to test for duplication of @coord, for example: 
test="@coord = following-sibling::Entry/@coord" to start concatenating
or
test="@coord != preceding-sibling::Entry/@coord" to stop concatenating
but my difficulty is in deferring the xsl:copy while concatenating their texts. It gets messy in document order (my failed and unfinished attempt which only does one concatenation instead of as many as needed):

```
  <xsl:template match="Segment">
      <xsl:for-each select="Entry" >
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()= 1 and (@coord = following-sibling::Entry/@coord)" >
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@*"/><xsl:value-of select="text()" /> <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Entry/text()" />
              </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@coord != preceding-sibling::Entry/@coord" >
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@*"/><xsl:value-of select="text()" />
              </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:for-each select=".">
                   <xsl:if test="@coord = following-sibling::Entry/@coord" >    
                       <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Entry/text()" />
                  </xsl:if>          
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

It seems it might be more natural concatenating in reverse document order, but it is still messy just thinking it through. What is the best approach in attacking this problem?

Per my comment on Answer 2, how does one extend the answer for additional parent processing as suggested (). The modified input with parent attributes (**frags** = number of child::text fragments, and **size**=total string-length of concatenated text fragments) that need filling and shown in the xml input below as empty attributes.

```
<Section coord="2.13" posn="2" of="13">
<Segment coord="1.25" rowno="1" of="25" frags="" size="">
<Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table" size="4">QUAL</Entry>
<Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table" size="1">I</Entry>
<Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table" size="9">FICATIONS</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment coord="2.25" rowno="2" of="25" frags="" size="">
<Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table" size="23">ACADEMIC QUALIFICATIONS</Entry>
<Entry coord="1.1" colno="1" of="1" desgn="Table" size="20"> (Most recent first)</Entry>
</Segment>
<Segment coord="3.25" rowno="3" of="25" frags="" size="">
<Entry coord="1.4" colno="1" of="4" desgn="Column" size="26">Degree/Diploma/Certificate</Entry>
<Entry coord="2.4" colno="2" of="4" desgn="Column" size="11">Institution</Entry>
<Entry coord="3.4" colno="3" of="4" desgn="Column" size="14">Date Conferred</Entry>
<Entry coord="3.4" colno="3" of="4" desgn="Column" size="9">(mm/yyyy)</Entry>
<Entry coord="4.4" colno="4" of="4" desgn="Column" size="15">SAQA Evaluated?</Entry>
<Entry coord="4.4" colno="4" of="4" desgn="Column" size="25">(If not SA qualification)</Entry>
</Segment>
<!-- delete -->
</Section>
```

Expected Output for additional processing on parent (Segment) elements:

```
<!-- deleted prior input xml -->
<Segment coord="1.25" rowno="1" of="25" frags="3" size="14">
<!-- deleted collapsed Entries as transformed -->
</Segment>
<Segment coord="2.25" rowno="2" of="25" frags="2" size="43">
<!-- deleted collapsed Entries as transformed -->
</Segment>
<Segment coord="3.25" rowno="3" of="25" frags="6" size="100">
<!-- deleted collapsed Entries as transformed -->
</Segment>
<!-- deleted rest of input xml -->
```

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using? 1.0 or 2.0? And please add your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this XSLT1.0 stylesheet(XSLT2.0 version of this will be much simpler):

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!-- identity transform template -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Segment">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Entry[not(@coord = preceding-sibling::Entry/@coord)]">
            <xsl:variable name="Coord" select="@coord"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="../Entry[@coord = $Coord]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Works in both xslt1 and 2, but only if following is true: two entries should be collapsed if their parents and coords are the same.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="entry-by-coord" match="Entry" use="concat(generate-id(parent::*), '||', @coord)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Entry">
        <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id(key('entry-by-coord', concat(generate-id(parent::*), '||', @coord))[1])">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('entry-by-coord', concat(generate-id(parent::*), '||', @coord))/text()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Both above approaches work perfectly for my xml input, in fact for the entire input not just the snippet. Their comparison has provided some insight on XSLT feature sets and design patterns that go with them. Approach 2 is evidently more reusable as it relies less on element hierarchy literals. Thanks to all. (And yes, I was seeking an Xslt1 solution, which these responses support.)

Comment: First approach relies on the order of Entry elements, i.e. it will work for 1,1,2,2,3 but not for 2,1,2,3,1

Comment: Interesting, indeed. If I may indulge you a little further to explore a more general use for this pattern or approach, If I were to want to do more processing in addition to concatenation, how would one extend this answer? Let us say we want to set an attribute for the string-length of each text fragment but also do the same at the parent using their sum, and say also the number of child test fragments as a parent attribute. I'm posting the modified XML input into the edited original question.

Comment: Folks, please withdraw above further exploration query. It's not a well-formed query.as the collapsing transform invalidates input fragment count. Also finding out Answer 2 belongs to the Muenchian grouping pattern, well documented, even in my 2001 dog-eared Kay's 2nd Ed. XSLT Ref, hence no need to respond. Moderators, please withdraw, Thanks